# Custom sorting of agenda (by tag)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Is there a way to customize how tags get sorted in org-agenda weekly view? I don't like the default which is sorting alphabetically (within tasks of the same date/priority).

It would be more useful if the sorting could be in the order tags are defined in the org file.

Comment: I give up related with writing filters in org mode. It takes time also as much as time as the tasks that I have to do :).
Not the best solution but I am using https://github.com/vapniks/hide-lines functions to filter depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't exactly answer the question, when you're in the agenda tag view you can filter the tags by using `\ TAB` and specifying another, this is probably the easiest approach.

The default method in org-mode is to sort the tag-match agenda view by the sequence they are seen in the files ([10.4.3](https://orgmode.org/manual/Sorting-agenda-items.html#Sorting-agenda-items) of the manual doesn't say it's alphabetical but it could be wrong).

You can adjust how they are sorted by changing `org-agenda-sorting-strategy`, so you might want to use `M-x customize-variable org-agenda-sorting-strategy` from there you will be able to toggle all sorts of things.

Comment: Yes, that's not what I had in mind... I see that I already use org-agenda-sorting-strategy, including tag-up, which explains the alphabetical sorting.